# node express react oauth pass access token after athorization in callback with react client app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, reactjs, oauth

I have a node server that authenticates with a third party (like stack overflow does) using oauth.  When the third party hits my callback and I authorize the request and get the access token and other info, I want to then pass this info to a react app I made, so then the react app can make REST calls to using the access token straight from the provider.

I am new to react and node, but am able to make a node server that can get the access and refresh token info.  I am new to 'serving' and serving a react app.  I have been serving using

```
app.use('/client', express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

to serve react apps, and this works great to a limited extent.  The situation I am currently in exceeds the extent and I want to learn how to send the oauth info along with my react app back after authorizing in the callback.  The flow I am using authorizes the request in the callback and then does a redirect back to the /client route to render the app, which fails to pass any oauth info to the client.  Is there any way to set the header before that redirect to have the oauth info, and then some how get that oauth info in the react app?

I am posting here to get some advice on some avenues and resources I should read up on, and maybe some suggestions for my current situation.  I am eager to learn more on express and am currently looking to set the header with the info I need and then serving the react app as a file or something, I am not sure yet.

Thanks to all in advanced!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll give my best to answer your question. So the problem with SPA(Single Page Application) and OAuth login is that the only way to transfer data with redirects is URL query string. The JWT(JSON Web Token) would allow this, but it's only supported in mobile native SDK-s. Solution for the web, without using the popover flows here:

For Node.js I suggest to use Passport.js OAuth modules, the login flow:

1. Example /auth/google -> redirect to Google login page.
2. On success, you get redirected back to callback url /auth/google/callback
3. You also get back the access_token, refresh_token, basic profile information etc.
4. No sessions are used so we use the JWT and generate the token on server side.
5. Redirect back to application with the token: app.example.com?token=JASJKDk..
6. On client side extract the token from query string.

This is just one possible flow that you might use, instead of JWT you could also use session/cookie solution.

Comment: thank you so much!

that makes sense. So I would let my node server handle the /auth/google & /auth/google/callback routes & use JWTs to encode the access_token, refresh_token to store in the url to pass back to my client? 

So the flow could be something like:
 1.click a button to login to google. does GET to get the google login url from node redirects the url it got
 2.login to google -> request callsback to node and returns access_token, refresh_token, etc
 3.make a JWT of this info append it to the url and return the client app on the url
 4.decode jwt in client use token for ajax

Comment: Actually you would only need JWT, no need to pass back the access tokens, refresh token, at least I suppose you don't need these on client side, only on server side?

Comment: For this use case I am planning on passing the access token to the client to make a few rest calls.  Would it be unsafe to just put the access_token on the URL like I would the JWT?  I want to confirm this is the reason to use JWTs

Comment: I wouldn't expose access token to client and yes use the calls through the JWT.